# openpyxl cell merge with borders?

Tags: python, formatting, border, openpyxl

I'm working on a document with openpyxl, and I have some a named style, it has fill, alignment and borders.

When I try to set the style of a merged cell to this named style, the color,alignment, both work. However, only some of the borders show up.

The current case Im looking at has cells merged in a column. The only borders that are showing up are the top and left.

When I put this same style on a single cell that isn't merged, it has all 4 borders.

I've tried putting the formatting before and after the merge, and it had no effect (which is a good thing I suppose. I'm only formatting the top cell, although when I tried applying the format to all cells before merging, it had no effect.

Comment: Got the same issue and find a workaround for this problem: first, apply border to all the cells you want to merge and then merge them.

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible in openpyxl <= 2.5 because it requires creating cells simply to hold the styles. Unfortunately, this introduces ambiguity into a worksheet as the cells can be written and read.

openpyxl 2.6 will include support for styling merged cells without ambiguity. See https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/pull-requests/261 and the associated pull requests for further information.

Comment: But everything but borders works fine? weird. ok. good to know.

Comment: I can't be certain what "works" because the specification sort of leaves it up to the application to decide what to do :-/. Magnus says that fill and text formatting are all based on the top-left cell, at least with MS Excel. Best simply giving the 2.6 checkout a try.